# Calculating MSE (Mean Squared Error)

Tags: java, image, compression, mse

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but where can a find a step-by-step guide on how to compute the MSE of two images?

I know what the formula is but I have no idea how to put it into practice.

Comment: Any particular programming language ?

Comment: Maybe post what you have as the formula...

Comment: Java? I just got the forumla from wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error It's no help as you'd imagine. If you post it in Java can I get a clear explanation of what's happening? I'd really appreciate it, thank you so much.

Comment: OK - I've added a `java` tag for you.

Answer (score 4):

In C you might do something like this:

```
int sum_sq = 0;
double mse;

for (i = 0; i < h; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < w; ++j)
    {
        int p1 = image1[i][j];
        int p2 = image2[i][j];
        int err = p2 - p1;
        sum_sq += (err * err);
    }
}
mse = (double)sum_sq / (h * w);
```

Comment: Can you do it in Java? And possibly comment it? I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Also, if the two images are the same size how exactly is it computing the error?

Comment: Java should be almost identical to the C example above. As for MSE, there is more than one possible interpretation of your question, but I'm assuming the two images are similar, e.g. one is an "original" and the other is original + noise, and you want to calculate MSE = mean square difference between the two ?

Comment: What parameters do  I feed it?

Comment: There aren't any parameters - w and h are just the image dimensions (width and height) - the above code sums the squares of corresponding pixel differences and divides by the total number of pixels in the image to get mean squared error.